# python multiline regex findall

Tags: python, regex, delimiter

I'm trying to find multiple matches across multiple lines of text with a delimiter to stop the search using regex in python... my query works well for what I'm trying to accomplish if what I need is all on the same line: 
re.findall('([a-zA-Z]{3}\d-[aAeE][rRsS]\d.*), output)

the problem is, sometimes the additional data I'm trying to capture doesn't fit on the same line and goes to the next... is there a way to set the pattern match to stop if it either finds the next match or hits a delimiter (= in this case)?  Simplified example with two matches below, and I need the ability to capture both...

Example

```
Port Id Description
3/2/4 Part of aggregate interface lag-4. Next device in path sea1-as2
lag-4, sea1-as2 3/1/2.
```

Comment: What are the correct matches for the example that you've provided? are they `sea1-as2` and the second `sea1-as2` without `3/1/2` ?

Comment: sorry for the poor formatting (didn't realize it would change the way I posted), but 1 line has sea1-as2 with the next line having lag-4, then sea1-as2 3/1/2.  I was hoping to capture the 2 sets sea1-as2 lag-4 and sea1-as2 3/1/2.

Comment: The formatting you're looking for is 4 blanks before start of each line. Then it is formatted as "code", as <pre>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all you have to do is to add `[\s\S]*?` to capture whatever coming in the next line and include the expected stops `, | .` to stop the match. Note that it is important to make `[\s\S]*?` lazy, otherwise, it will match the whole thing.

```
print(re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z]{3}\d-[aAeE][rRsS]\d[\s\S]*?\d)(?:,|\.)', output))
```

output

```
['sea1-as2 lag-4', 'sea1-as2 3/1/2']
```

Comment: it is my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `[a-zA-Z]` and `[aAeE][rRsS]`. There are several ways to set
[re.IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) so that `[ae][rs]` would suffice.

You didn't make it clear if you're using `re.MULTILINE` or if you're deleting newlines before evaluating the regex. You end with `.*` which could trivially become

```
[^=]*
```

if you want everything up to the `=` delimiter.

Alternatively, before evaluating the regex you could split on `\n` newline and `=` equal, so you hand in appropriate size chunks for evaluation.